# How to get ServletRequest in any class using @Context or similar?

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

I've used `@Context` to access the `HttpServletRequest` in the past, and it's worked.

I've got another class where I've tried to use this, but it's not being assigned, (ie `request` is `null`)

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;
```

All I'm trying to do is get the request parameters in a class, without having to pass them through to each parent instance.

So how can I get `request.getParameter("username")` when `request` is assigning as null?

Comment: What kind of _class_? Is it managed by Jersey (or whatever framework you're using)? That's what processes `@Context`.

Comment: Yeah the class isn't derived from anything special (Object).... is there some generic way I can derive the class from something to make it's context HttpServletContext ?

Comment: It's not about an inheritance hierarchy. The instance of the class has to be managed by the container. I don't know enough about JAX RS to help with the details.

Comment: Yeah I could change my class to be derived from something else if that would help it get the right context..... I'll do some more research and see if I can find an answer....

Comment: I think that annotation will only work in Resource classes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found I could do this was by passing it down the call stack, though I did manage to shorten up that call stack apporoach using Guice.

To do this, I bound my Provider to the the request like so:
        `bind(MyClass.class).toProvider(MyClassProvider.class).in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);`

and my provider simply looked like this:

```
public static class MyClassProvider implements Provider<MyClass>
{
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Inject
    public MyClassProvider(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass get()
    {
        return new MyClass(request);
    }
}
```

So now when my class is created, it has the Request context available.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your @Context is not working is most likely because it is not a managed object by your server, and therefore the server doesn't even know about the request to do this injection.

Other potential issues include you declaring the HttpServletRequest as a instance variable, in which case you'll have threading issues.  In fact, some container won't inject @Context on a class level, it must be on a method level.

Typically, if you need something from an object, its usually best to pass it down the call stack.  If you are unable, then you can try `Filter` based solutions that use `ThreadLocal`.  This gets messy though, so try very hard to pass it down the call stack if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

One another solution can be to create a new FacesContext and set it as the current instance inside the web service or you have HttpServletRequest instances.

```
FacesContextforWebServices facesContextforWebServices=new FacesContextforWebServices();         facesContextforWebServices.setSessionValue(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse,"#{sessionScope.username}",username);
```

The class for creating FacesContext instance.

```
public class FacesContextforWebServices {
public void setValue(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String expression, Object value) {
    FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext(request, response);
    facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(facesContext.getELContext(), expression, Object.class).setValue(facesContext.getELContext(), value);
}
protected FacesContext getFacesContext(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (facesContext == null) {

        FacesContextFactory contextFactory = (FacesContextFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY);
        Lifecycle lifecycle = lifecycleFactory.getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE);

        facesContext = contextFactory.getFacesContext(request.getSession().getServletContext(), request, response, lifecycle);

        FacesContextforWebServices.InnerFacesContext.setFacesContextAsCurrentInstance(facesContext);

        UIViewRoot view = facesContext.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(facesContext, "");
        facesContext.setViewRoot(view);
    }
    return facesContext;
}

private abstract static class InnerFacesContext extends FacesContext {
    protected static void setFacesContextAsCurrentInstance(FacesContext facesContext) {
        FacesContext.setCurrentInstance(facesContext);
    }
}
```

}

One can get the parameter with

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory()  .createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(),expression,Object.class).getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext());
```